# Retrieving AJAX data in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to use the `xhr.send(VALUE)` to send the data in AJAX. How do I get this data in a PHP file?

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var value = 'hello';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            alert("no");
        }
    }
    xhr.open('POST', 'json.php', true);
    xhr.send(value);

}
```

Comment: You'd need to send a `key=value` type pair through your ajax request. if you send just a bare value, it will not show up in $_POST. Those you'd have to read from `php://input`. Remember that for all the fancy frilly stuff around them, AJAX is still just an HTTP request, exactly as if you'd done a `<form>` submission. The only difference is that it's done in the background.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the `$_POST` variables on the PHP page you can use this code to display them all so you can visually see their keys and values

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

From there you will know how to use the data in any file. You can do the same thing with `$_GET`

Comment: PHP won't populate the `$_POST` array in this case since he is not sending the data correctly.

Comment: Good call, im just too used to sending data using js libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You are just sending a string to the PHP file.  You are not sending it as a query string or with a content type, so PHP doesn't populate the `$POST` array.

You can try to read the raw post data:

```
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $post; // hello
```

Or, if you want PHP to populate `$_POST`, you need to do some extra steps in your JavaScript.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var value = 'hello';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            alert("no");
        }
    }

    xhr.open('POST', 'json.php', true);

    // Tell the server you are sending form data
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // Send it as a query string
    xhr.send('value='+value);
}
```

Then in your PHP, you can access `$_POST['value']`.

```
echo $_POST['value'];  // hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, replace your  xhr.send with

JS

```
 xhr.send('value='+value);
```

PHP

```
echo($_POST['value']);
```